# How to modifying a map while iterating over its entrySet

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, dictionary, hashmap

I have encountered this problem doing a job interview:

Given an undirected graph (described by its corresponding edges), How do I find the number of possible triangles?

Example:
for: {(0,1), (2,1), (0,2), (4,1)} the answer will be: 1.

I thought of an algorithm but encountered Java technicall problem on the way (and I know that there might be other algorithms that are more efficiently, the correctness and efficiently of my algorithm is not the point where, the technicall problem on the way is).

My algorithm is this:
define a Hashmap: Map < Couple,Integer>. The key of the map, Couple, is an object that basically contains two points: starting point (say vertex '0') and the exit point (say vertex '1'). The integer value of the map, is the number of edges that I am going through to get from start vertex to end vertex.
i.e. for the edge (0,1) there will be an entry in the map that will say: (new Couple(0,1),1);
for these 2 edges (0,1),(1,2) there will be an entry in the map such as: (new couple(0,2),2) because we can get from 0 to 2 by going over these 2 edges.

My idea was to start iterating on the map and for each vertex to check if it could be connected (meaning its exit point matches some other vertex's starting point or vice versa). If so, create an appropriate new entrey with the other vertex number of edges+1. at the end I wanted to count how many couples there are that start and end with the same number and has size of 3 (meaning create a triangle).

The problem was that while I was iterating over the map, I also changed it (adding new entries, each time I found new edge that connect to another). this cause me to get a "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException".

I wanted to know if anyone has a way to solve this and in addition someone could please explain to how to overcome such problem in the future.
Thanks alot!

```
public static int NumberOfTriangles(Couple[] nodes) {
    Map<Couple, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, counter = 0;
    int x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        x1 = nodes[i].getStart();
        y1 = nodes[i].getEnd();
        map.put(new Couple(x1, y1), 1);
        map.put(new Couple(y1, x1), 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        x1 = nodes[i].getStart();
        y1 = nodes[i].getEnd();
        Iterator<Entry<Couple, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet()
                .iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Couple, Integer> thisEntry = (Entry<Couple, Integer>) entries
                    .next();
            x2 = thisEntry.getKey().getStart();
            y2 = thisEntry.getKey().getEnd();
            if (y1 == x2) {
                int value = map.get(new Couple(x1, y1));
                if (value < 3) {
                    value++;
                    if ((value == 3) && (x1 == y1)) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    map.put(new Couple(x1, y2), value + 1);
                }
            }
            if (x1 == y2) {
                int value = map.get(new Couple(x2, y1));
                if (value < 3) {
                    value++;
                    if ((value == 3) && (x1 == y1)) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    map.put(new Couple(y1, x2), value + 1);
                }
            }
            if (y1 == y2) {
                int value = map.get(new Couple(x1, x2));
                if (value < 3) {
                    value++;
                    if ((value == 3) && (x1 == y1)) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    map.put(new Couple(x1, x2), value + 1);
                }
            }
            if (x1 == x2) {
                int value = map.get(new Couple(y1, y2));
                if ((value == 3) && (y1 == y2)) {
                    value++;
                    if (value == 3) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    map.put(new Couple(y1, y2), value + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Couple

```
    public class Couple {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public Couple(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return ((((Couple) other).getStart() == start) && ((Couple) other)
                    .getEnd() == end);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (start + end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure the `entrySet`'s `iterator` supports `remove`, but that is the preferred way if it does. (Sorry, this is just for remove. For adds you have to do something like what @PatrickChan suggested.)

Comment: I tested the code, it doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException. Show how you invoke the method, so I can reproduce the exception.

Comment: System.out.println(NumberOfTriangles(new Couple[] { new Couple(0, 1),
    new Couple(2, 1), new Couple(0, 2), new Couple(4, 1) }));

Comment: Couple class was now added in the orignal comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the exception by changing the **HashMap** to **ConcurrentHashMap**. 
And change every

```
int value = map.get(new Couple(x1, y1));
if (value < 3) {
```

to

```
Integer value = map.get(new Couple(x1, y1));
if (value != null && value < 3) {
```

And this will not throw ConcurentModificationException, but it won't find any triangles because I think you have an error in you algorithm. **Here is a working new algorith:**

The Couple:

```
public class Couple {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public Couple(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
}
```

the Node

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Node {

    private int value;
    private Set<Node> adjacentNodes = new HashSet<Node>();

    public Node(int x) {
        value = x;
    }
    public void addAdjacentNode(Node node) {
        adjacentNodes.add(node);
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int values) {
        this.value = values;
    }

    public Set<Node> getNodes() {
        return adjacentNodes;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + value;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (value != other.value)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

the Triangle

```
public class Triangle {

    private Set<Integer> nodes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    public Triangle(Node... node ) {
        for (Node node2 : node) {
            nodes.add(node2.getValue());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((nodes == null) ? 0 : nodes.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle [nodes=" + nodes + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Triangle other = (Triangle) obj;
        if (nodes == null) {
            if (other.nodes != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nodes.equals(other.nodes))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Main

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Triangle> foundTriangles = new HashSet<Triangle>();
        Map<Integer, Node> graph = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
        Couple[] a = new Couple[] { new Couple(0, 1), 
                                    new Couple(2, 1), 
                                    new Couple(0, 2), 
                                    new Couple(4, 1) };
        // build graph
        for (Couple couple : a) {
            int start = couple.getStart();
            Node node1 = graph.get(start);
            if (node1 == null) {
                node1 = new Node(start);
                graph.put(start, node1);
            }
            int end = couple.getEnd();
            Node node2 = graph.get(end);
            if (node2 == null) {
                node2 = new Node(end);
                graph.put(end, node2);
            }
            node1.addAdjacentNode(node2);
            node2.addAdjacentNode(node1);
        }
        // search for triangles in the graph
        for (Node root : graph.values()) {
            Set<Node> nodes = root.getNodes(); // A
            for (Node root2 : nodes) { // B
                if (!root2.equals(root)) { // prevent going back
                    Set<Node> nodes2 = root2.getNodes();
                    for (Node root3 : nodes2) { // C
                        if (!root3.equals(root2)) { 
                            Set<Node> nodes3 = root3.getNodes();
                            for (Node node4 : nodes3) {// A
                                if (!node4.equals(root3)) { 
                                    if (node4.equals(root)) { 
//                                      String message = 
//                                      MessageFormat.format(
//                                          "Found triangle: {0}{1}{2}",
//                                          root.getValue(),
//                                          root2.getValue(), 
//                                          root3.getValue());
//                                      System.out.println(message);
                                        Triangle t = new Triangle(root,
                                                                  root2, 
                                                                  root3);
                                        foundTriangles.add(t);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(foundTriangles);
    }
}
```

the output is like

```
[Triangle [nodes=[0, 1, 2]]]
```

if you remove comments on the lines with the MessageFormat, will see more verbose output

```
Found triangle: 012
Found triangle: 021
Found triangle: 120
Found triangle: 102
Found triangle: 210
Found triangle: 201
[Triangle [nodes=[0, 1, 2]]]
```

this is because the algorithm finds the same triangle 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

Use another Vector to store the values you want to modify and do it after the iterator loop

Comment: do what after the iterator loop? copy the another Vector to my Map (I am iterating on)?

Comment: store the Couple objects in another Vector and put it in the Map outside         while (entries.hasNext()) {...} this loop